# Analytical Functions in Sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle

I have a query,which works in ORACLE but doesn't work in SQL SERVER 2005...How can I convert this query to work in SQL SERVER 2005.

```
select user_name
       , url
       , count(*)
       ,first_value(count(*)) over (partition by user_name 
                                    order by count(*) desc) max_total
from urls
group by user_name, url
order by max_total desc,user_name
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Can you describe what the query is supposed to return?

Comment: I have uploaded the file,which shows the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  user_name, url, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    urls
        GROUP BY
                user_name, url
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q qo
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 cnt
        FROM    q qi
        WHERE   qi.user_name = qo.user_name
        ORDER BY
                cnt DESC
        ) qi
```

Comment: Did you check this?  Unfortunately I can't check you answer now I don't have sql server..But tomorrow I will be able to check...

Answer (score 2):

Because of my comment is big I will write it as answer:(

@tanging It is not much correct but there is a correct path...Maybe I have solved this problem by queries but I wanted it by analytical functions....My query is this

```
select urls.user_name
       ,urls.url
       ,count(*) ct
       ,max_amount 
from urls
     ,(select user_name
              ,max(amount) max_amount
       from (select user_name
                    ,url
                    ,count(*) amount
             from urls
             group by user_name,url)  t1
       group by user_name) t2
where urls.user_name=t2.user_name
group by urls.user_name,urls.url,max_amount
order by max_amount desc,urls.user_name,ct desc
```

Comment: both your query any mine are the same, you have a second subquery that I resolved via the MAX.  if you run your query and mine, the results are the same.

Comment: No No it is not the same(You should count max per username)   I will give you test data to see the difference...Test data is up..

Answer (score 1):

@tanging This is test data.

```
create table urls(
user_name varchar2(100),
url varchar2(100)
);


insert into urls
values('mariami','google.com');
insert into urls
values('mariami','google.com');
insert into urls
values('mariami','google.com');
insert into urls
values('giorgi','google.com');
insert into urls
values('giorgi','google.com');
insert into urls
values('giorgi','facebook.com');
insert into urls
values('giorgi','facebook.com');
insert into urls
values('giorgi','facebook.com');
insert into urls
values('giorgi','facebook.com');
insert into urls
values('mariami','facebook.com');
insert into urls
values('a','facebook.com');
```

The result of my query is:
[image]

And your Query's Result is:
[image]

Comment: ! VOILÀ! you are correct, I opted out of the second inner query when in fact it was necessary

Comment: @tanging Thank you for you time which you shared with me..I really appreciate you help..:) Thank you.